# Minimum # toggle (3 consecutive elements) operations to convert ring A into ring B (rings made of Xs and Os: X->O and O->X)

Tags: algorithms, optimization

There is a ring A and ring B made of Xs and Os. My aim is to convert A to B by using only the minimum number of `#` operations. When I do `#` on an element `i` of the ring, element `i-1`, `i` and `i+1` will be toggled. (toggled => X->O and O->X).

Comment: Try formulating this problem in terms of linear algebra over GF(2) (the field with two elements). This will answer some of your questions.

Comment: Yes, exactly so.

Comment: Nice exercise!  Where did you run across it?  I encourage you to [credit the source](http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) of the problem.  Also, what have you tried?  If you still can't solve it after a day or two of trying, edit the question with this information and then ping me.

Answer (score 1):

You can represent a ring as a $n$-bit string, where $n$ is the number of positions in the ring.  Encode an X as 1, and encode a O as 0 (zero).  That gives you a $n$-bit string, say $x$.

The # operation on index $i$ corresponds to xor-ing the string representing the current state of the ring with the string $c_i = 0^{i-1} 111 0^{n-i-3}$.  In other words, if the ring is currently $x$, then the # operation on index $i$ changes the state of the ring to $x \oplus c_i$.

Suppose you're given two rings $x,y$ and you want to find a way to transform $x$ into $y$.  Then all you need to do is find a subset of $c_1,\dots,c_n$ whose xor is equal to $x \oplus y$.  This will be the solution to your problem.  Can you see how to do that?  Solution below (don't mouse over until you've thought about it for a while):

> You can find that solution using linear algebra in modulo 2 arithmetic (i.e., Gaussian elimination modulo 2).